# Stop json.loads from capitalizing true or false as values

Tags: python, json

I have some JSON that looks like this..

```
...
"aaa": "play",
"bbb": "fxc",
"ccc": true,
"ddd": "nat",
"eee": "news",
...
```

When I call `json.loads(my_json)` on this string then it will convert the `true` into `True`. Is there anyway to not do this?

Comment: `True` or `False` are pyton Boolean objects and must be capitalized. Otherwise you must have them as a string to keep them lowercase, and that is **wrong**

Comment: You're loading the JSON, so it takes the JSON value `true` (the boolean "true") and turns it into the Python value `True` (the boolean "true"). This is correct behavior.

Comment: Yes I know all of this. That is not the question????

Comment: @covid you seem to want `json.loads` to give you the value `true`, but that's not a value in Python so it of course won't do that. Is `true` supposed to be `"true"`? If so, you need to quote it in your data.

Comment: I don't understand the down votes or confusion around the intent of the question. It seems fairly clear that the intent is to treat booleans as string literals, no?

Comment: So would replace() be the best way to do this? Replace all occurrences with the quoted version?

Comment: @covid no, you need to fix your data. However you're generating the JSON is wrong if that's supposed to be a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stands, it looks like you want to effectively *treat JSON booleans as if they were string literals for the terms "true" and "false".*

With the [`object_pairs_hook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) parameter:

```
>>> def no_bool_convert(pairs):
...     return {k: str(v).casefold()
...             if isinstance(v, bool) else v for k, v in pairs}
>>> json.loads('{"foo": "fxc", "ccc": true}',
...            object_pairs_hook=no_bool_convert)
{'foo': 'fxc', 'ccc': 'true'}
```

Note that this does not fundamentally re-write the JSON parser; the value is still parsed as a boolean, but then convert back into a lowercase `str`.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: My use case is json.loads(JSON originally generated by Javascript) and wanting to write a .js file so wanting 'false' and not 'False'. Good question and successful answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use true as string `"true"` in Python true value is `True` and false is `False`.
 
When you are using `json.loads` it's convert the JSON to dict and all the JS formatted values to Python values.